# Chapter page and header

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, chapters

I'm trying to create my chapter page and a header. I have four problems to solve

1- the header is printed on the chapter page

2- I would like to switch between right and left the position of page numbering

3- I would like to put the chapter name and not the word chapter in the header

4- Do this in the book class, the header that I made seems to use commands compatible only with memoir

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows}
\definecolor{lightb}{RGB}{229,246,253}
\definecolor{mediumb}{RGB}{76,197,243}
\definecolor{lightg}{RGB}{233,232,232}
\definecolor{fill}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\definecolor{capa}{RGB}{145,206,228}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{,positioning,matrix,calc, shapes.arrows, shadows.blur,shadows, shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols}
\definecolor{bound}{rgb}{0.5,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{bound1}{rgb}{0.2,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{fill}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\newcommand\SolidHeader{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[mediumb, yshift=0.55cm, xshift=1.585cm, line width=1pt, fill=lightb] (0,0) plot[domain=-1.57:0, samples=100, xshift=-0.1\paperwidth] (\x,{1.4*sin(2*\x r)}) {};

\node[xshift=-0.1\paperwidth] at (0.785,0) {{\large \thepage}};

\draw[mediumb, yshift=0.55cm, xshift=1.585cm, line width=1pt, fill=lightg, xshift=-0.1\paperwidth] (0,0) plot[domain=0:1.57, samples=100] (\x,{1.4*sin(2*\x r)}) {};

\node[xshift=-0.1\paperwidth] at (4,1) {\chaptername};

\node[fill=mediumb,inner sep=0pt,text width=\paperwidth,anchor=south west,minimum height=1.5pt, xshift=-0.1\paperwidth] at (current page header area.west) (box) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makepagestyle{solid}
\makeevenhead{solid}{\SolidHeader}{}{}
\makeoddhead{solid}{\SolidHeader}{}{}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{solid}
\pagestyle{solid}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       Chapter     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\scshape}%\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\chaptername \ \thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[capa] (0,0) rectangle%LightSkyBlue
        (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[xshift=.5\paperwidth,rectangle,
        rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
        fill=black]%MidnightBlue
        {\color{white}#1};%anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth
        \node[signal, signal to=nowhere, signal from=east, draw, anchor=north west,inner sep=5pt, fill=black] at (current page.north west)
        {\color{white}\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont{\chapterlabel}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\scshape}%\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
\node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[capa] (0,0) rectangle%LightSkyBlue
    (\paperwidth,3cm);
    \node[xshift=.5\paperwidth,rectangle,
    rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
    fill=black]%MidnightBlue
    {\color{white}#1};%anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth
    \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A test chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here there are too many questions try asking MOST important one (class) first as all the others would need to be changed again when relationships change. SO simplify the question as to which of the above does not work with book class. Then see what affects page number header and chapter, they may all work better for you in book class

Comment: I already managed to solve it, thank you